# How to fill the date field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have a lightning component code,which the date field is autopopulated from the code.

```
obj['CloseDate']= new date();
```

Is new date function is no longer in salesforce?How to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is **case-sensitive**, letter 'D' in Date should be in uppercase like this:

`obj['CloseDate']= new Date();`

For Aura component, you can also use `$A.localizationService` method to format and localize dates.

Further reading [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_format_dates.htm)